# Kitchen subfloor replacement

Tags: tile, subfloor, plywood, backer-board

We purchased this home three years ago and have 18x18 ceramic tile in the kitchen and foyer that is cracking. I removed a portion to see what is going on and the old plywood definitely needs replaced. Underneath the plywood they have 2x3 that the subfloor is nailed to. I pulled up the piece of plywood 1/2 thick and then there is I think quarter inch or less of additional underlayment then backerboard then the tile. I have to be able to match the size correctly where it meets the dining room. Should I just copy how it was laid with new? The existing plywood is spongy.

Comment: Have you determined why the existing plywood is spongy?  You'll want to correct that before you go through the trouble of tearing out and replacing this.

Comment: The plywood looks real old and is coming apart

Comment: Are the 2x3’s spaced at 16” oc or 24” oc? How far do the 2x3’s span?

Comment: Most tile mortar manufacturers require at least 1-1/4" of subfloor. So the three layers you describe could be adequate if properly fastened.

Comment: Plywood usually does not come apart unless damaged by water/moisture/high humidity.  If so, more checking underneath is called for.

Comment: While I must admit that I can't exactly picture how all these layers/components are going together, I don't think 1/2" plywood over 2x3s is sturdy enough for a tile floor. IMO the subfloor should be 3/4" plywood or OSB, etc. to avoid any deflection.

Comment: Plywood does not come apart due to age.  It's getting wet from something.

Comment: A good, focused, lit picture of the multiple layers will help a lot. If it also includes an exposed bit of plywood (or a 2nd picture that does), that will help people help you determine _why_ that ply is getting so spongy.